# Labels in dendrogram in R

Tags: r, label, dendrogram, dendextend

I am working on dendrogram

```
plot(clust.res, hang=-1, main=dedro,labels=data1$Name.of.the.variety)
```

Then message that I get are:

```
Warning messages:
"labels" is not a graphical parameter
```

Answer (score 2):

That makes sense.
In general, the `plot.dendrogram` function does not have a `labels` parameter, and does not allow you to modify the labels of the dendrogram it plots.

It is, however, possible to do using [the dendextend R package](http://www.r-statistics.com/2015/08/dendextend-a-package-for-visualizing-adjusting-and-comparing-dendrograms-from-the-journal-bioinformatics/).

Here is a simple example for you to go through:

```
# some data and create the dendrogram
DATA <- 1:4
hc <- hclust(dist(DATA))
dend <- as.dendrogram(hc)

# Get dendextend for editing the labels
if(!require(dendextend)) install.packages("dendextend") 
library(dendextend)
# Copy the object, and edit its labels
dend2 <- dend
labels(dend2) <- c("one", "two", "3", "four")

# compare the two dendrograms:
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(dend, main = "original dend")
plot(dend2, main = "dend with edited labels")
```

The dendextend package also allows you to modify the labels color and size, [see here for examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html#setting-a-dendrograms-labels).

[image]